# Attempting ValidationAttribute in MVC4 that is asynchronous using Async, Task and Await

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am attempting to write a Validation attribute in MVC4.
The purpose is to check for the existence of an application reference (just a string that represents a key I wish to prevent a duplicate for).
My data is accessed via WebAPI and because I am using 4.5 I wish to make this asynchronous if possible.

I am perhaps not making the best or appropriate usage of async and await but I would like to know how to call my async method from the overridden IsValid method of the inherited Validation class.

```
public class UniqueApplicationReferenceAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public UniqueApplicationReferenceAttribute() : base(() => "The {0} already exists") { }

    public int? ApplicationCount { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var myTask = GetApplicationRefCountAsync();

        myTask.Wait();

        this.ApplicationCount = this.ApplicationCount ?? 0;

        if (ApplicationCount > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public async Task GetApplicationRefCountAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:11111/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var apps = client.GetStringAsync("api/dataapplications");

        await Task.WhenAll(apps);

        var appList = apps.Result;

        this.ApplicationCount =  appList.Count();// apps.Count();
    }
}
```

Many thanks,
Dan.

Comment: C# 4 is not commonly used with MVC 4. Do you mean C# 5? Is your MVC app running on .NET 4.5?

Comment: MVC 4 on .net 4.5 - my brain dissolved by tagging stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you call your WebAPI methods synchronously. `ValidationAttribute` does not support asynchronous implementations natively, so any synchronous-over-asynchronous code you'll write is just going to be a hack and not actually provide any benefit as compared to the synchronous version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen! I think you are right and I'll take a look at implementing this - have you seen an example of how this is done well?  I see many examples but quite often for WPF.  I am creating a SPA in Angular and wish to ensure I am calling webapi correctly as this code will be used for countless validations and basic data lookups - want to get this right.

Comment: I'm afraid that's out of my realm of experience, but I can highly recommend John Papa's Pluralsight course and blog. He currently uses Durundal instead of Angular, but the concepts should be very similar.

Comment: I have listening to that series 3 times - long videos too!  My first SPA test was created using Durandal.  Brilliant videos and loved the factory patterns for generics in data access.  Thanks for your pointers.

Comment: This is a bit OT, but I have an SPA project starting up next month and would like to hear why you chose Angular over Durandal. If you blog about it, please do share the link. :)

Comment: Hi Stephen, in a nutshell it was more of a strategic move than a well considered one.  At the time Durandal seemed not to promote itself as well as it could, documentation lacking and it sounded like the project was tied to a single person over a team based Google project - I felt safer going with Google.  I am still well in the realm of exploration but I am liking the Angular structure - I managed also to be able to load all files asynchronously using require js - loading screen was my first requirement. Looks pretty with bootstrap too. ASP.NET MVC + Angular MVC + WebAPI = many files :D

Comment: There were other various minor technical reason e.g. routing built in, create directives to create new HTML tags (good for re-use), animated transitions between pages, spent a lot of time hooking up require js so it boots in full async (apart from CSS), modularity of factory/service pattern, built in dependency injection.  It's a mountain of cool.  Durandal seemed to be importing a little too much and felt like there was a great deal of cross project dependency e.g. for a new browser, you then rely on a many number of js projects all being excellently prompt at keeping up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to test this in full, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
public bool IsValid(object value)
{
    var appCount = GetApplicationRefCountAsync().Result;
    return appCount > 0;
}

public async Task<int> GetApplicationRefCountAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:11111/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    return await client.GetStringAsync("api/dataapplications")
        .ContinueWith(r => Convert.ToInt32(r))
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Be careful about using async/await methods in an ASP.NET thread. It's easy to create deadlocks.

Comment: Are deadlocks a common problem in service calls / async generally?  Should I be using a certain technique to mitigate this risk?

Comment: It's particularly troublesome in ASP.NET, because everything runs in the UI thread. If you await the result of a task on the same thread that spawned the task, the task will never return.