# Async custom view-model validation. Impassible with .net core? Why?

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm looking on this documentation [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ivalidatableobject). It's looks like useful. For rxample I have the following view-model:

```
class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<int> Roles {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to check if all `Roles` exist in my database. I'm trying something like:

```
class CustomerViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<int> Roles {get; set;}

    public async Task<IEnumerable<ValidationResult>> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        await Task.Delay(123); /// imagine that it's database call

        // and so on
    }

}
```

And surprise! It's impossible. It does not work. Because there is no async version of `Validate`( 
Is it possible to validate my model in model? Or I have to write separate validation services?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707228/attempting-validationattribute-in-mvc4-that-is-asynchronous-using-async-task-an

Comment: @SalahAkbari ohh( The answer from Stephen Cleary tells me that validation from the hood is sync( I don't understand why Microsoft can't give this ability(

Comment: @SalahAkbari which is your way for solving this situation? I mean, for example, you have view-model like in the question. And you need to be sure that all Roles exist. Where you will do that?

Comment: I don't think this should be validated. It's actually related to some business error. Either the client is trying to hack around (post request not via the official UI) or some role is missing/deleted in the time between your user loaded the UI and your user post the request. So the rate of this happening is fairly rare, you can completely rely on the mechanism of throwing Exception. That's it something going wrong. Of course a custom exception is required here to help identify the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The validation pipeline is not asynchronous, so it's not possible to be used for this purpose. However, that's not what it's for. Validation is about ensuring type and value correctness, not business rules such as being actual role values. That should be enforced in your business/data layer. For example, if you were using DDD, the aggregate would enforce this when adding roles to the collection of roles. This might also be something that is enforced in a repository or service for the type. Additionally, in a relational database, this would be enforced via a referential constraint, which would bubble up into your data layer, such as EF throwing an exception.

Comment: I usually implement something like validation of business data on my services layer. Now I see, it's correct. Thank you.

Comment: It's layers. As you get closer to the metal, it's harder to give good feedback to the user/allow them to correct their errors. However, some things can only be validated in lower layers. Think of client-side versus server-side validation. Client-side can catch a lot, but you still have to validate at the server and sometimes send the user back. No one layer should be used exclusive for validation. Having those different layers catch problems at different places and work to overall ensure a good user experience and data integrity together.

Comment: But how to pass validation error message? I usually implement it via my custom exceptions.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tried but can you try

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var domainService = validationContext.GetService<IMyDomainService>();
    var task = domainService.GetRoles();
    Task.WaitAll(task);
    var result = task.Result;
    
    // do your validation            
}
```

You need add `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`
You can also Get instance of DBContext instead of DomainService

Comment: task.Result is not a very good idea since it will block the thread while the IO bound operation will happen.